# Can 'IN' Be Used In A Case Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I don't know how to phrase my question but I will try my best.

I am trying to accomplish something like this for a report in SSRS.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 = 
CASE
WHEN @VAR1 IS NOT NULL THEN @VAR1
WHEN @VAR1 IS NULL THEN IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2)
END
```

How do I rewrite my case statement to allow this type of logic? Should I be writing it in a different way?

I know that this question can be interpreted as an open ended question but I will mark the answer as answered as soon as I test and it is working for me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Column1 from Table2 has NULLs in the Column. I know that the 'IN' doesn't produce NULLs. I need to pull EVERYTHING in that column from the subquery.

Comment: What does `@var1` contain? Is this a string with a comma delimited list? A single value?

Comment: Variable contains a string. In my case, if the variable is not null, then the user typed in a string to search and filter on. If the variable is null, then the user didn't want to filter on this criteria. Since they didn't filter on anything, I need all of the values of the subquery.

Comment: To fix your original query try `WHEN @VAR1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2) THEN COLUMN1`. That will break when `COLUMN1` is null though.

Comment: @shawnt00 what can I do if the column1 is null and I need nulls?

Comment: What type of data exists in Table2. Is Table2 a lookup table for Table1.Column1 Field?

Comment: Ignore my statement about null. As long as the column value isn't nullable you'll be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - you can't use the IN as you'd like. You just need to re-work your two possibilities a little.

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE   (@VAR1 IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN1 = @VAR1) OR
        (@VAR1 IS NULL AND COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2) )
```

**For NULLs:**

To match NULLS, you can try:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE   (@VAR1 IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN1 = @VAR1) OR
        (@VAR1 IS NULL AND 
                (COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2) 
                OR COLUMN1 IS NULL) ) )
```

Comment: `(@VAR1 IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN1 = @VAR1)`  can be shortened to 
`(COLUMN1 = @VAR1)`

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm not sure about that - what if both have NULLs?

Comment: Then it will evaluate to `unknown` not `true`

Comment: Now that I think about it, you are correct - though I think the longer way is more readable.

Comment: This works. However, there are NULL values in column1 in table2. I need those NULLs too. I know 'IN' doesn't include NULLs. Sorry for the confusion. I should have specified that in the beginning. I'll make an edit in my original post.

Comment: @Kajankow42 - Should a NULL in **Table2.Column1** always match all records from **Table1.Col1** or just when Table1.Col1 is NULL?

Comment: @HannoverFist I'm not sure how to answer it. Maybe if I clarify more it will answer your question. 

When I do 
`WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2)` 
I get the list of everything excluding the NULLS. If I do, 
`WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2) OR TABLE1.COLUMN1 IS NULL` 
then I get what I need. However, when it comes to the SSRS side, when the variable is not null, the user is wanting to search on that field, the NULLs are displaying along with the criteria they wanted. I also can't do an `AND` instead of the `OR` because of the logic of ANDs and ORs.

Comment: @Kajankow42 - check out my edit. I added a part for NULLs that should work in your situation.

Comment: @HannoverFist From what I can tell with my data, it isn't working. I believe since we are using the COALESCE function, that is going to be excluding the NULLs. The COALESCE is giving me the first Non-Null value.

Comment: @Kajankow42 - I have updated it so it should work like your `WHERE TABLE1.COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2) OR TABLE1.COLUMN1 IS NULL`

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 in
    (SELECT distinct Coalesce(@VAR1, TABLE2.COLUMN1) FROM TABLE2
     UNION SELECT @VAR1 --In case it is possible TABLE2 is empty
    )
```

It should make use of any indexes on `Column1` in `TABLE`.

If your column is nullable, any indexes will probably be useless, but to return the records with null values if  null values are in `TABLE2` you could use:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN1 in
    (SELECT distinct Coalesce(@VAR1, TABLE2.COLUMN1) FROM TABLE2
     UNION SELECT @VAR1
    )
    OR
    (COLUMN1 IS NULL
     AND EXISTS(SELECT distinct TABLE2.COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2
     WHERE TABLE2.COLUMN1 IS NULL 
    )
```

Comment: You might as well get rid of the coalesce. And even the distinct is unnecessary actually.

Comment: The coalesce is necessary  if there is a value in @Var1... we only want to use that value.  The distinct is cosmetic probably.

Comment: Anytime you filter with an in clause you could also filter with a join. Which one is faster depends on your data and your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off creating a stored procedure to handle this, you will get better performance using dynamic sql, using `WHERE @Var is NULL or <Other Expression>` will result in poor execution plans and slow query performance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE My_Proc 
  @Var1 INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
             FROM TABLE
             WHERE 1 = 1'
            + CASE  WHEN @VAR1 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N'AND Column1 = @VAR1 '
                    WHEN @VAR1 IS NULL 
                  THEN N'AND Column1  IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2)'
              END

Execute sp_executesql @Sql 
                     ,'@Var1 INT '
                     ,@Var1 

END
```

Comment: Why not just have an IF statement in the stored procedure and two queries?

Comment: this will lead to the same problem, if on the first execution the first block of an `IF` statement is executed, a plan will be cached , on next execution if the second block gets executed because of the values of the variables the cached execution plan will be forced to use for the query in second block , even it maybe not the best execution plan for the statement in the second block.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize the MS optimizer was so screwed up an if statement will hose it.  If that is true they should def. fix that.

Comment: No its not screwed up optimizer :) I think it will be because of the wrong use of `IF ELSE` blocks. shouldn't use them in that way, we have dynamic sql to handle this situation and so should we use it for such situations.

Comment: What else would if else be used for if not flow of control in a stored procedure.  You've lost me.

Comment: Compiling dynamic sql every time is clearly a sub-optimal solution.  It will have a huge performance hit if you need run the query a lot... say 1000 times a minute or even 100 times a minute

Comment: really can you not think of any other use of IF..ELSE blocks in t-sql ..... validations, variable assignments, data manipulations etc....

Comment: Nope not really , dynamic sql has its own scope and will store parameterised execution plan. `parameterised execution plans` is feature only available for dynamic sql hence for optional parameters , dynamic sql is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to skin the cat:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3
FROM TABLE
WHERE 1 = 
    CASE
        WHEN @VAR1 IS NOT NULL AND COLUMN1 = @VAR1 THEN 1
        WHEN @VAR1 IS NULL AND COLUMN1 IN (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2) THEN 1
        --WHEN @VAR1 = COLUMN3 AND COLUMN1 != COLUMN2 THEN 0 /*example*/
        ELSE
        END
```

I find this a little easier for me to get my head around, and I can play around with the logic more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for an input parameter to default to "all" when it is null (this is often the case when users select from a list on a website) you should do this:

```
COLUMN1 = COALESCE(@VAR1,COLUMN1)
```

or in sql server specifically

```
COLUMN1 = ISNULL(@VAR1,COLUMN1)
```

If you need to "limit" column1 to values you in another table include an inner join to that table

```
JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE.COLUMN1 = TABLE2.COLUMN1
```